# Openbravo Tomat permissions

Tags: tomcat6, java-6, openbravo

I've got a problem with the Openbravo module management. When I want to rebuild, the Openbravo drop that alert message.:

> No write permissions to Openbravo folder. Tomcat is not able to write in this folder. Please change permissions.

Can You help me? I don't know which folder that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this answer keeping in mind that you are working on Linux system.

This problem occurred because your project don't have openbravo permission.

In your machine there is an openbravo user, so now you need to give the folder openbravo permission to do that go to the folder where you install openbravo for example.

```
cd /opt/
```

know use `ll` command and change project owner by running this two command

```
chown -R openbravo:tomcat6 projectName
```

after that use this command

```
chmod -R 775 projectName
```